# there are two headers react navigation after delete and reinstall npm! (RN)

Tags: react-native, header, react-navigation

my code ran perfectly with my custom header, but I had to reinstall npm. without any change in my code , now I have two headers after install npm!!
how can I get ride of the default  header?? I emphasis that my problem **is not** about  `headerShown: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find my mistake. When you reinstall node.js and reinstall your other packages **separately**  ,be notice new version of the packages can make problems.

for my case, install **react navigation v6** instead  of **v5** , ruined my code!I downgrade to 5 , my problem solved. ;)